# Which is the best linux program for a C++ programmer?

Tags: c++, linux, autocomplete, intellisense

I have always wanted to step away from windows and go completely linux, but the only thing that prevents me are the programs. The problem is that I am use to the intellisense in Visual Studio 2008. I have looked for many alternatives to a program which displays the functions as visual studio does, but none seem to have what I am looking for. I have found programs such as notepad++ and it is awesome, but I don't like how it only uses color codes for the text. I know you can do CTRL-SPACE to get the Auto-Completion function to appear, but it is nothing like the one in Visual studio. If anyone knows of a linux program which does as specified, please tell me the name. I really want to put Windows away and go into linux. It has been interesting me for quite some while now. Also, I would like to know which programs you use to program in linux and why you like it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: It's pretty hard to beat Visual Studio's intellisense. Xcode / Eclipse / Netbeans / et. al. come close, but it's not the same.

Comment: I'd wait until next year. I hear 2011 is the year of the Linux Desktop.

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend vi.  Intellisense et. al. is a crutch, spend some time coding without it, you'll be amazed at how much better your code is when you actually have to think about what you're doing instead of just picking through packages.  If you really can't live without,  either NetBeans or Eclipse are good.  Nothing's going to seem "as good" as VS, because it'll be different (and let's face it, VS *is* a pretty nice dev environment), but it's not hard to make the switch.  And you'll be getting all the benefits of Linux to offset whatever you might feel you're losing: a real shell, a search command that actually works, tools that don't make you step through a five-dialog "wizard" just to set up a database connection...

Comment: A lot of people have said that... and maybe you're right to an extent. That's how I've been scraping by in C#. Didn't have to know a damn thing, and I could code in it, thanks to the IDE correcting everything for me. But what's so terrible about that? It helps you learn while you're still a noob, rather than having to Google every 4 seconds; you're telling me that's more efficient? I don't really think it's a crutch. A good programmer will follow good design principles either way. Not to say VI isn't good or anything. I just haven't had the patience to learn it.

Comment: @Mark: scraping by is not acceptable to code well. having a no-IDE system forces you to learn.

Comment: To start !! You're going to struggle when you're new to the language either way, I'm saying it's easier with some assistance built into the IDE.

Answer (score 4):

[NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/features/cpp/index.html)!! It's fairly similar to Visual Studio. Has IntelliSense and all that jazz. I use it all the time.

**Edit:** Any second now someone will come in here and pipe up with "[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/)!!". You might as well investigate that too, but I'm a NetBeans boy.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind using qmake for compilation, then I used [qt-creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools), and it works really well. Obviously, it is designed for use with Qt, but it can be used without (but not without qmake!)

Comment: Just FYI, NetBeans has Qt support too :) I guess it doesn't have the designer shindig, but I think it has a plugin so you can swap easily. Ionno, I took one glance at qt-creator and it overwhelmed me with unfamiliarness, but I guess it's just something you have to get used to.

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to shell out a little money, there's slickedit  http://www.slickedit.com/

I used version 9 on Linux for development of a mixed C/C++ app.  The completion is quite good, very similar to Visual Studio.  It's worth a look anyway, there's a free trial.

Comment: I think SlickEdit is actually better than Visual Studio.

Comment: Surprisingly enough, I have been using SlickEdit instead of Visual Studio since before DevStudio 5.0 showed up on the scene.

Answer (score 3):

(Obliging Mark)
[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org). It's fairly similar to Visual Studio. Has auto completion and all that jazz. I use it all the time.

Honestly, I love Eclipse as a java and xml IDE. The C/C++ toolkit (CDT) is a little flaky and the only reason I use CDT is that eclipse is already installed. In cases where I need to do more advanced stuff (-B,static -l... -B,dynamic), I usually end up use gedit and make.

Answer (score 1):

Just like Mark said, I also love Netbeans, it's really simple to use, got a lot of great highlighting and is really fast. On a side note if it's just to write some fast and easy code I also love gedit, which basically is a text editor but has awesome code highlighting too(plus its Cobalt theme (Dark blue based theme) is really nice and doesn't make you want to pop your eyes out of their sockets after looking at the screen for 2 hours straight).

Comment: ehm, really what (last sentence)?

Comment: XD, I really need to get some sleep, missed like 5 words there.

Comment: Just FYI, there are dark themes for NetBeans you can DL or make yourself.

Comment: Yeah I know, but for some reason even though I've tried many times I can't get the exact look of gedit.

Answer (score 1):

This has always seemed pretty neato, but I've not done any heavy C++ work for a while.

Of course, it *is* an emacs plugin.

http://cedet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Hahaha...that page makes me want to cry, it's so 95!!

Comment: @Mark: you'd be surprised how little the shinies matter when you're getting things done.

Comment: Haha...no, you're quite right, but they don't hurt either :)

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse CDT has better code completion than Visual Studio, NetBeans, KDevelop or Xcode, in my experience.  In particular it seems to do a better job of unraveling typedefs and template instantiations.

I also recommend using CMake to make switching between development environments and build systems relatively easy.

Just a note on NetBeans: it's code completion works quite well, but has performance issues on sufficiently complex code.  Try using it boost, for example and it seems to take forever.

Comment: Visual studio never seems to deal with Boost.MPL or StateChart typedefs well. I also have problems viewing std:: for some headers.

Answer (score 0):

I use codeblocks myself, even on Windows. Its code completion is not great like Visual Studio because it only show the name of the possible choices, while Visual Studio even show descriptions if you want. but it works.

Altough if you manage to like NetBeans or Eclipse, stick with them, codeblocks is too unprofessional (like, they don't updated their roadmap since 2006... And they release randomly, asking the users to use unstable builds instead)

Comment: Yeahhh... I started with DevCpp and then switched to CodeBlocks when it was evident that it had died and CodeBlocks was a similar enough replacement...but once you get a taste of the professional IDEs, you won't look back.

Comment: In fact I DISLIKE codeblocks, but I too came from DevCpp... Using DevCpp was much easier, but it died :( Code::Blocks configuration screens are annoying, at best...